# after_commit for rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jruby, jrubyonrails, actioncontroller

I know that an `after_commit` callback is provided for ActiveRecord objects in Rails 3.  However, I would like to get access to this functionality in a Rails Controller.

The intent is to do something like this in the controller:

```
rescue_from AccountError, :with => :render_internal_error

after_commit :render_created, :on => :create

def create
  Account.transaction do
    modify_underlying_system
    @account.save!
  end
end

protected
def render_created
  render :status => 201, :json => {...}
end

def render_internal_error
  render :status => 500, :json => {...}
end
```

Is there some way I could achive this? I do not want to use the ActiveRecord `after_commit` callback, because it would mean breaking the separation between model and controller by having the model do rendering, which is something it should not be doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you're trying to do:

```
def create
  begin
    Account.transaction do
      modify_underlying_system
      @acount.save!
    end
    render :status => 201, :json => {...}
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
    render :status => 500, :json => {...}
  end
end
```

I didn't test it, but that looks about right.

Comment: This was my first approach. It would not work out well for me, because I have many exceptions that could arise from the modify_underlying_system call. For this, I use rescue_from, but I think there must be a cleaner way of sending a success response when the transaction succeeds.  Is there any way I can figure out whether a transaction succeeded?

Comment: I don't believe so, the only thing you can do is check for exceptions being thrown in the transaction.  Any saves called throughout your modify_underlying_system call should also cause a RecordInvalid exception as well though, so it should work anyways.  You could look at the ActiveRecord::Rollback exception, but I'm not sure if that actually trickles into the begin/rescue section.

Comment: Looks like you gave me the *only* answer :)